# Controller couldn't find data in List ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, list, indexing, asp.net-core

I have a problem with "index out of range" problem. In my app I have complex Database with such models:

[image: 1]]

[image: 2]]

[image: 3]]

And there I have a tables, created for them:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Answers] (
[Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[IsCorrect]  BIT            NOT NULL,
[QuestionId] INT            NULL,
[Text]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Answers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Answers_Questions_QuestionId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Questions] ([Id]));


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Questions] (
[Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[LessonId] INT            NULL,
[Text]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Questions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Questions_Lessons_LessonId] FOREIGN KEY ([LessonId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Lessons] ([Id]));


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lessons] (
[Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[XpRequired] INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Lessons] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC));
```

Then I'm trying to take all questions for lesson I get using it Id.

```
public IActionResult Lesson(int id)
    {
        Lesson lesson = _context.Lessons.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == id);
        ViewBag.Questions = lesson.Questions.ToList();
        return View(lesson);
    }
```

And then in the View I'm trying to take the first element from the list:

```
@using Easy_English.Models
@model Lesson

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LessonLayout.cshtml";
    List<Question> questions = ViewBag.Questions;
}

<div class="wrapper">
    <p>@Model.Name</p>
    <p>@questions[0].Text</p>
</div>
```

But I'm getting "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" error.

As you can see, I have one question for that lesson and controller couldn't find it. 
[image: 4]]

[image: 5]]

**UPD:** Contoller finds needed Lesson and all it fields, exept Questions.

**UPD2:** When I write this everything finds well:

```
List<Question> questions = _context.Questions.Where(q => q.LessonId == 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Possible this if there's no questions found for a particular id: 'questions[0]'. Take a look at your stack trace to determine where the exception is coming from.

Comment: @AaronLS as I said in UPD section, my controller finds everything exept Questions field in Lesson. And I simply don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try write this and check the output.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<p>@Model.Name</p>
<p>@Model.Id</p>
@foreach(Question q in ViewBag.Questions)
{
    <p>@q.Text</p>
}
</div>
```

UPD: EF Core doesn't support Lazy Loading yet.
You need to specify related data to load.

`Lesson lesson = _context.Lessons.Include(t=>t.Questions).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == id);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said in UPD column "lesson" variable in controller doesn't have any questions in "Questions" List. Maybe it happens because of incorrect links in tables?
Questions table is on the last picture.

Comment: With the code you give I have all fields with Lesson data exept the <p> where I show Question text.

Comment: Also after reading comment of  Kirk Larkin I'm remember that EF Core doesn't support Lazy Loading.
Write this in your controller:


`Lesson lesson = _context.Lessons.Include(t=>t.Questions).FirstOrDefault(l => l.Id == id);`

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Much thanks to you and @Kirk Larkin. Could you please update your answer with the new info?